# on testnet: 'transaction already in blockchain'.. but it isn't

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, raw-transaction

At least I don't think so!
I'm trying to create a wallet infrastructure to minimise fees, and so I've been experimenting with raw transactions. I'm quite clueless but fortunately have enough sense to use testnet instead of the real thing :)
I created a simple raw transaction using a perl script that executes rpc commands to bitcoind. I picked a UTXO that had 0.0625 tBTC on it and tried
createrawtransaction, signrawtransaction followed by sendrawtransaction. I ran this a few times over the same utxo with the result:

{"result":null,"error":{"code":-26,"message":"66: insufficient priority"},"id":null}

(I was trying to see how the number of confirmations affected the priority so I did this at intervals)

Then at some point I started getting:
{"result":null,"error":{"code":-27,"message":"transaction already in block chain"},"id":null}

and yet as far as I can see, it is not on the block chain. I checked the receiving address both by rpc (of course it is my address) and using blocktrail.com/tBTC. Nothing on the receiving address, the original utxo is still there and nothing has changed in my wallet. I tried restarting bitcoind and a rescan but without any success.

What has happened? I am assuming it is not possible via raw transactions to fool the network into thinking the transaction has been transmitted when it hasn't - that would be a major flaw I think. Perhaps my copy of the blockchain has become corrupt? Do I need to reindex to purge this? (Reluctant to try this because in my experience it can take a long time.) Any other suggestions for dealing with this?

Thanks for any help!

**EDIT**

Actually I'd thought the txid would be returned by the network (and thus would be returned on successful submission) but I guess then it is a hash of the info it contains? Anyway, thanks Nick for inadvertently teaching me sthg there :)
So I did decoderawtransaction and I get the following output

```
$VAR1 = {  
   'locktime' => 0,
   'vin' => [{  
      'sequence' => 4294967295,  
      'vout' => 1,  
      'txid' => '5ef8db75b8f3590dda1865f1dc4810b6d4be56775e4af43b6a394dccafe4422f',  
      'scriptSig' => {  
         'hex' =>   '483045022100f24e41182ae3f1663b2bde4f9ff2d2e6ce66c0379ab8559c143a442460573da602206a28496206d5881bbb4eea9aa761bf07b3af2b8a6ca44b59e40a9b77059b91ad012102a3012dad956be238d9e17cd1b1473cd0c66968d479e3311e320b2c7b02dfa8b5',  
         'asm' =>   '3045022100f24e41182ae3f1663b2bde4f9ff2d2e6ce66c0379ab8559c143a442460573da602206a28496206d5881bbb4eea9aa761bf07b3af2b8a6ca44b59e40a9b77059b91ad01 02a3012dad956be238d9e17cd1b1473cd0c66968d479e3311e320b2c7b02dfa8b5'  
      }  
  }],  
  'version' => 1,  
  'txid' => '3bc11bfb7778ad806619f8190231cf907302cfc545d7e5116e24a15795646583',  
  'vout' => [ {  
     'scriptPubKey' => {  
         'hex' =>   '76a91468fd391d83c31283c00bc8b481f3eb698e33799c88ac',  
         'asm' => 'OP_DUP OP_HASH160 68fd391d83c31283c00bc8b481f3eb698e33799c OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG',
         'type' => 'pubkeyhash',
         'reqSigs' => 1,
         'addresses' => [ 
            'mq65vFheh3mXBvApPKbko8TVHaFQxEHxcf'
         ]
      },
      'n' => 0,
      'value' => '0.06257'
   } ]
 };
```

I guess the txid in question is then

```
3bc11bfb7778ad806619f8190231cf907302cfc545d7e5116e24a15795646583
```

? Again, I can't find this on blocktrail.. and I still have the same error?

Comment: Could you post the TXID so we can search for it ourselves?

Comment: Hi Nick - I edited my question

Comment: Thanks tom! That's really odd; it shouldn't do that unless you have a different set of blocks than a testnet block explorer. Could you compare `getblockcount` on your local system to http://blockexplorer.com/testnet/q/getblockcount ?

Comment: 328860 for both?